# gedit error : "Unexpected error: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input"

Tags: command-line, gedit, unicode, encoding

I'm doing a research project in NLP. For that I have to analyze a unicode (Sinhala) [text file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LUNPRxpjsASXlK2rAmlDMbWCStPvCl8W) of around 10mb and it opens in Google docs. But when I try to open it from  gedit I'm getting this error

> Unexpected error: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input

So, I followed this [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160910/unexpected-error-invalid-byte-sequence-in-conversion-input-in-gedit) and tried the second answer which suggests running this command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"
```

I got this result in the terminal:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
No such key “auto-detected”
```

So, no success. When I try to open the file in gedit, I'm getting the same error. How can I fix this? How can I open this file in **gedit**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what the cause of the problem is, but I was able to reproduce it on my system.

Experimentally, I ran `dos2unix` on the file and the output said it was a UTF-16LE file. For the curious, LE means [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). After `dos2unix` had converted the file to UTF-8 format, I was able to open it with Gedit.

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
dos2unix -n oldfile newfile
gedit newfile
```

I used the `-n` flag to avoid overwriting the original file. Replace `oldfile` with the original filename and `newfile` with whatever you want the new file to be called. Use tab completion (type the start of the filename and press tab and the full name should appear) or `'` quotes if your filename has spaces or other special characters.

As a sidenote, I was able to open the file without converting it using [Pluma](https://github.com/mate-desktop/pluma), a text editor based on Gedit, so I suspect that this may be a bug in Gedit. Passing `--encoding UTF-16LE` or `--encoding UTF-16` to Gedit when opening the file did not help.

Comment: +1 Excellent work! If it may be a bug, shouldn't we report it?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. First I though it was an error with the text file as I got some other text files which opened from *gedit* without any issue.

Comment: @PankajaParanavitharana you are very welcome. Sorry not to be more illuminating about the cause though!

Comment: @dessert yes, probably! I shall try to investigate further when I have time